# How to takeout only part of a string, from DF string column in spark, scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

Inside Dataframe I have a column which consists the following data

```
('Rated 3.0', "RATED\n \nWent there for a quick bite with friends.\nThe ambience had more of corporate feel. I would say it was unique.\nTried nachos, pasta churros and lasagne.\n\nNachos were pathetic.( Seriously don't order)\nPasta was okayish.\nLasagne was good.\nNutella churros were the best.\nOverall an okayish experience!\nPeace ??"), ('Rated 4.0', "RATED\n  First of all, a big thanks to the staff of this Cafe. Very polite and courteous.\n\nI was there 15mins before their closing time. Without any discomfort or hesitation, the staff welcomed me with a warm smile and said they're still open, though they were preparing to close the cafe for the day.\n\nQuickly ordered the Thai green curry, which is served with rice. They got it for me within 10mins, hot and freshly made.\n\nIt was tasty with the taste of coconut milk. Not very spicy, it was mild spicy.\n\nI saw they had yummy looking dessert menu, should go there to try them out!\n\nA good spacious place to hang out for coffee, pastas, pizza or Thai food.")
```

I need to takeout the `Rated 3.0` portion from each record. This is a StringType column. How can I remove the extra data and extract it?

Comment: What have you tried?  For instance, did you try using methods such as [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_extract(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exp:String,groupIdx:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)?

Answer (score 0):

If each row format is `Rated x.x` you can simply use `substring` function.

```
scala> df.select(substring('value,3,9)).show
+----------------------+
|substring(value, 3, 9)|
+----------------------+
|             Rated 3.0|
+----------------------+
```

If you have multiple "Rates" in a single row you can try to use `regexp_replace` and replace below values:

```
(' to "
', to ":
") to "
```

Moreover you should add `{` at the beggining of string and `}` at the end.
So the format should looks like below.

```
{
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d"
}
```

Thanks to this you will create JSON string and in the next step you can use `from_json` function to create array/struct and get these values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Solution: Assuming there are two records on the question.

**//Creating List//**

```
val mytestList=List(("""Rated 3.0, RATED Went there for a quick bite with friends.The ambience had more of corporate feel. I would say it was unique.Tried nachos, pasta churros and lasagne.Nachos were pathetic.( Seriously don't order)Pasta was okayish.Lasagne was good.Nutella churros were the best.Overall an okayish experience!Peace ??"""), 
("""Rated 4.0, RATED  First of all, a big thanks to the staff of this Cafe. Very polite and courteous.I was there 15mins before their closing time. Without any discomfort or hesitation, the staff welcomed me with a warm smile and said they're still open, though they were preparing to close the cafe for the day.Quickly ordered the Thai green curry, which is served with rice. They got it for me within 10mins, hot and freshly made.It was tasty with the taste of coconut milk. Not very spicy, it was mild spicy.I saw they had yummy looking dessert menu, should go there to try them out!A good spacious place to hang out for coffee, pastas, pizza or Thai food."""))
```

**//Loading List to RDD//**

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(mytestList)
```

**//Imposing Schema Column Names//**

```
val DF1 = rdd.toDF("Rating")
```

**//Solution 1**

```
DF1.withColumn("tmp", split($"Rating", ",")).select($"tmp".getItem(0).as("col1")).show()
+---------+
|     col1|
+---------+
|Rated 3.0|
|Rated 4.0|
+---------+
```

**//Solution 2 removing/droping others**

```
DF1.withColumn("tmp", split(col("Rating"), ",").getItem(0)).drop("Rating").show()


+---------+
|      tmp|
+---------+
|Rated 3.0|
|Rated 4.0|
+---------+
```